# Delayer Persistent MessageStore implementation

Tags: spring-integration

I have an application having the Delayer tied to a Persistent MessageStore running on 3 servers. How does the Delayer pick up messages from the Persistent Store after the delay interval? Messages can be picked up by any Delayer or it will be the specific server's Delayer which put the message into the Store?

Answer (score 1):

The delayer is not intended to distribute messages across a cluster - each one should have its own store.

Otherwise, if one of the members is restarted, it will reschedule all the messages, as long as you use transactions, you won't get any duplicates because one of the schedules (the original or rescheduled) will fail to find the message.

It's better to use a separate store/region for each and use some other mechanism to distribute work across the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Gary!We should be okay if any Delayer member reschedules the messages as it's a common JBBCMessageStore,right?What if we are using the same REGION across 3 servers where the Delayer is running on(make it distributed), any one can pick it up at real time or only after re-start?The other option as you said is to have the Delayer deployed on different servers with each having it's own region configured.What if a server dint come up at all?others won't have the ability to process stored messages.

Comment: To keep it concise, can we make the Delayer distributed by using a common REGION in the persistent store?

Comment: As I said, it will only work as expected if you are using transactions (after a restart). When restarting, the release schedule is rebuilt from the DB. My preferred configuration would be a different region for each instance to avoid any confusion.